# Command raised an exception: TypeError: 'str' object does not support item deletion

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I have a problem I cannot delete data in a JSON

**My code** :

```py
if str(user.id) in data:
        for element in data:
          if str(user.id) in element:
            del element[str(user.id)]
```

**My error** :

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVw95.png)

Comment: Python strings are immutable. You can't delete characters out of them. You can probably do what you want with `element = element.replace(str(user.id),"")`, if I understand your intent correctly.

Comment: don't work ----

Comment: *Doesn't work* is not a problem statement. What is your data in `element`, what is your modified code, what is the result, and if you get an error message, what is it?

Comment: Json : 

`{"560849136899850261": {"name": "tuto", "but": "tuto"}}`

Code :

data :
`async def get_data(guild): 
    with open(f"assets/entreprise/bdd/{guild.id}/mainbank.json", "r") as f:
        data = json.load(f)

    return data
`

`py
data = await get_data(guild)

    if str(user.id) in data:
        for element in data:
          if str(user.id) in element:
            element.replace(str(user.id),"")
`

Comment: I suggest you read my comment more carefully. Your modified code is `element.replace(str(user.id),"") `, but what I suggested you write was `element = element.replace(str(user.id),"")`. What you wrote will indeed do nothing. And please don't put code in comments. It's impossible to read that way. In future, *edit* your question if you modify the code.

Comment: like that? : 

`if str(user.id) in data:
        for element in data:
          if str(user.id) in element:
            element = element.replace(str(user.id),"")`

Comment: Yes. `replace` returns a modified version of the string that you can assign back to `element`. You do that because you can't modify the string in-place,, because strings are immutable.

Comment: but it doesn't work :/

Comment: To convince yourself that it does work, try this:  `element  = "FRED"; element = element.replace("E","")`. The value of `element` will then be "FRD". Then work out what else is wrong in your code to cause the error you are seeing.

Comment: Are you maybe expecting that changing `element` will somehow change `data`? It won't. `element` is a copy of successively all the elements of `data`  and any changes you make to it will disappear next time through the `for` loop. To apply the change to `data` your code needs to assign to `data`, as in `data[someindex] = somevalue`.

Comment: I feel like this is something a lot of people get confused at, like if you have a list `a = [1,2,3,4]` and do `for x in a: x=0`, the value of `a` will still be `[1,2,3,4]`

Comment: Also @Feinz i think you missed the point of code not being in the comments. If it's one line or an expression, you can use comments to write that. However, if you have multiple lines of code with indentation, edit your question and include it there using triple backquotes ( ` ). It is also a good idea to provide a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)